# updateLicenseRequestInfo never being called for DASH DRM assets

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

I see `updateManifestRequestInfo` and `updateSegmentRequestInfo` being called, but I am having trouble sending headers. I never see the license URL called and `updateLicenseRequestInfo` is never called.

Are there any code examples for DASH DRM protected assets? The documentation is very limited.

```
host.licenseUrl = 'license URL'

...

host.updateLicenseRequestInfo = function(requestInfo) {
  requestInfo.headers = {
    'X-TOKEN': this.token_,
  };
  requestInfo.withCredentials = true;
};
```

Comment: Based from this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/player#frequently-asked-questions), You will probably also need to set something in the headers or modify the URL to start the process. If you also need these for your manifests, then override host.updateManifestRequestInfo. Applications should override `updateLicenseRequestInfo` method to add a token to the url, set headers or withCredentials flag.

Comment: I update the licenseUrl; I also did override updateLicenseRequestInfo but it's never called.

Answer (score 0):

For DRM you will  need a custom receiver and if you are using the Media Player Library, you need to override some methods to provide the necessary DRM information: https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/player#drm-playreadywidevine